# How to switch questionnaire images in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, jsfiddle

I have a semi-functional questionnaire. Initially a question appears with answers underneath, when an answer is clicked, the it is recorded and shown below to the user.

**I now need help getting it so that when an answer from question 1 is hit the images of question 2, and its relative answers, appear in place of question 1 and its possible answers.**

I have uploaded the entire thing on jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/QV5EB/, I looked around for similar events, I found this piece of coding which seems relative to what I'm looking for, only it's based on captions which I am not using in my code.

```
self.selectQuestion = function(answer) {
    self.progress.push({
        question: questions[currentQuestionIndex].caption,
        answer: answer.caption
    });
```

Can anyone recommend a particular way of doing this?

Comment: Your requirement is clear but your question is not. It looks like you want someone to just do this for you, which is not what Stackoverflow is here for

Comment: @Bojangles You're right, I'm sorry. I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction if it was possible, perhaps a specific question would be 'Can anyone recommend a particular way of doing this?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty easy - set up IDs for the picture and each of the answers, and then just use `document.getElementById()` to grab each element.

For the picture, change its `.src` property to the URL of the new picture.

For the answers, change their `.innerHTML` property to the values of the new answers.

---

Your HTML might look like this:

```
<img src='whatever.jpg' id='pic'>
<label id='answer1'><input type='radio' name='answer' value='dog'> Dog</label>
<label id='answer2'><input type='radio' name='answer' value='pig'> Pig</label>
<label id='answer3'><input type='radio' name='answer' value='snake'> Snake</label>
```

Then, your JS might look like this:

```
document.getElementById('pic').src = 'newpic.jpg';
document.getElementById('answer1').innerHTML = '<input type='radio' name='answer' value='rooster'>Rooster';
```

etc.

---

There's a more elegant way to do it without `.innerHTML`, which is the DOM functions.  Do some research on those, they're fun and powerful.  In particular, the above JS might take the form

```
var rad = document.createElement('input');
rad.type = 'radio';
rad.name = 'answer';
rad.value = 'rooster';
```

...and maybe insert a `span` for the text, but it's a little overdoing it.  Maybe `innerHTML` is best. :)

Comment: Steve sir, I couldn't have asked for more! Thank you very much for these key pointers and easy-to-understand steps. I can take this information and do exactly what I needed to now, and even research further into improving the work with DOM functions and a span if I feel up to the job. :D

Comment: Glad to help :)  Yeah, DOM is one of the topics that for some reason gets left out of a lot of beginner tutorials but turns out is one of the best parts of Javascript, and not too hard to learn.  Good luck!